# BES on Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, blackberry

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this so hopefully someone has some experience with this. We have an Exchange 2007 server set up that does not host email (our email is handle by our ISP and Exchange is used primarily for storing our email, and other advanced features in Outlook). The question that I'm having problems locating the answer for is whether of not Blackberry Enterprise Server Express will function with an Exchange server that doesn't host email. Any idea? Thanks for the advice/help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it will. BES doesn't care if there's email or not on the Exchange server. It will happily connect to the user's mailboxes and synchronize whatever it finds, regardless. I don't see how this will do you much good though. Does your Exchange server pop the email from the ISP? Is email sent out from the Exchange server?

Comment: No, the email is not sent out from the exchange server, so at this point the only benefit of having BES would be to sync the mailboxes with mobile users.

Comment: OK, then BES is going to be of limited benefit to you. Why not host your email yourself on your Exchange server instead of using the ISP?

Comment: I have made that recommendation, but the ones with the ability to make that happen have yet to make a decision on it. Until then, I plan on getting BES up and running. Thanks again for the info!

Comment: Glad to help...